# Cast and Case statement with query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, case

I am currently editing a view and trying to cast the field "Doctorate" as Yes, No, or Unknown, based on a case statement that is joined by 2 tables, then joined to the view.

I have an error near the from clause "Expecting ) or AS" but I still get an error when adding those characters. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Please see the excerpt of my code below:

```
 CAST (
            CASE 
                WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY >= 40 
                    THEN 'Yes'

                WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY < 40 
                    THEN 'No'

                WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY IS NULL
                    THEN 'Unknown'
                ELSE
                    NULL
            END

        FROM DEGREE_CROSSWALK D, VPAA V
            WHERE
                V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.DEGREE_CODE
                   AND V.PERSON_SKEY = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                   AND V.CURRENT_DEGREE = '1'

        AS VARCHAR2 (50))
                DOCTORATE,
```

Comment: 1. You have to specify the data type for which you are cast.

Comment: What is the `FROM` clause doing inside the `CAST` function call? If you mean to select from those two tables, then compute the `CASE` expression, and then apply `CAST` to it, that's fine (you are using a "scalar subquery" to return a single value to which you apply `CAST`), but then you are missing `SELECT` before the keyword `CASE`.

Comment: @VarunTiwari - the data type is present, it's the second-to-last line of code.

Comment: @mathguy -Oh wow. I see it now. Can you post your full code. May be there is an simplified alternative depending how your tables degree_crosswalk and VPAA are connected. You need a SELECT before CASE if you are trying to output a value using select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using the whole query inside `CAST`, but your problem can be resolved if you use `SELECT` and `()` as follows: (see the inline comments in the code)

```
SELECT CAST (
            (SELECT CASE -- added ( and SELECT here
                WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY >= 40 
                    THEN 'Yes'

                WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY < 40 
                    THEN 'No'

                WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY IS NULL
                    THEN 'Unknown'
                ELSE
                    NULL
            END

        FROM DEGREE_CROSSWALK D, VPAA V
            WHERE
                V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.DEGREE_CODE
                   AND V.PERSON_SKEY = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
                   AND V.CURRENT_DEGREE = '1') -- added ending bracket ) here

        AS VARCHAR2 (50)) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

First finish the cast function by casting it to a datatype or either remove the cast.

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT CASE WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY >= 40 
                         THEN 'Yes'
                         WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY < 40 
                         THEN 'No'
                         WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY IS NULL
                         THEN 'Unknown'
                         ELSE NULL
                         END
             FROM DEGREE_CROSSWALK D, VPAA V
             WHERE V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.DEGREE_CODE
             AND V.PERSON_SKEY = SRC.PERSON_SKEY
             AND V.CURRENT_DEGREE = '1') AS VARCHAR2 (50)) AS DOCTORATE
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Was this tested on Oracle ? I believe you can not do it like this ?

Comment: Not tested on oracle but it should work. Also edited my code to be more explicit.

Comment: I have and it does not work. I have even made your code more simple and nothing: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61f1da770e2576e77ecd4e7ca5303321

Comment: Yes I missed couple of things while doing copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this:

```
select CASE WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY >= 40 THEN 
                 cast('Yes' as varchar(20))
            WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY < 40 THEN 
                 cast('No' as varchar(20))
            WHEN D.DEGREE_HIERARCHY IS NULL THEN 
                 cast('Unknown' as varchar(20))
            ELSE
                 NULL
       END name_of_column -- Here the case clause ends and you can name the column
FROM DEGREE_CROSSWALK D --add other tables and join condition here
WHERE --add other conditions of the where clause
```

Also I suggest you do not join tables like this:

```
FROM DEGREE_CROSSWALK D, VPAA V
WHERE V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.DEGREE_CODE
```

but like this(just an example):

```
FROM DEGREE_CROSSWALK D
JOIN VPAA V ON V.FACULTY_DEGREE_CODE = D.DEGREE_CODE
```

Comment: A suggestion. You can get the output of cast expression first and then cast the result to varchar instead of casting 3 times in your case expression.

Comment: I believe it will cast only one time depending on what degree it is and your answer and other(accepted one) have two select ... You think two selects is better ?

Comment: Yes may be it is not needed. Check my comment on the question. I have suggested there could be a simple alternative.

Comment: But what is wrong with answer I provided ? The cast will be done only one time with every row ...

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Its just taking a lot more characters to write. It will be a lot more characters to type if this has to be replicated on more lines of code. simple is good.

Comment: Yes but is the two selects more expensive solution?

Comment: I guess the user didn't want an efficient solution. He just wanted a solution which he got in one of the answers.